# Is it possible to execute two commands sequentially using commands.json?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, task-runner-explorer

I am using Mads Kristensen's Command Task Runner extension in Visual Studio 2017, to help when working with a colleague's JS work. I have set up a `commands.json` file, which we use to Lint and Build his work:

```
{
    "commands": {
        "chat-lint": {
            "fileName": "powershell.exe",
            "workingDirectory": "./Scripts/Chat",
            "arguments": "-Command yarn run lint:fix"
        },
        "chat-build": {
            "fileName": "powershell.exe",
            "workingDirectory": "./Scripts/Chat",
            "arguments": "-Command yarn run build"
        }
    },
    "-vs-binding": {
        "BeforeBuild": [],
        "AfterBuild": []
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to execute two commands within one of the steps: that is, to execute `yarn install` *before* `yarn run build`, within the `"chat-build"` task. Is that possible, or do I really need to create a `.ps1` file to do that? Would be great if I can execute two commands sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I could just put two Powershell commands there, separated by a semicolon: "arguments": "-Command yarn install; yarn run build"